# Efficient way to iterate over a vast number of rows

Tags: python, dataframe

Let's assume I have a .txt file, consisting of million of lines, separated by `.`:

```
dog breed poodle .
dog breed golden retriever .
cat breed some breed .
dog weight 10 .
cat weight 15 .
fish location sea .
cat location house .
```

From left to right, let's call the columns `subject property value`. My goal is to create for each unique property a new table, with 2 columns, namely `subject` and `value`. Given the example above, the output would be:

```
breed

dog poodle
dog golden retriever
cat some breed

weight

dog 15
cat 15

location

fish sea
cat house
```

I need some ideas on what data structure to choose to achieve these tables. For example,
one approach could be a dictionary, where the each key represents a `property`, and for the table, consisting of `subject` and `value`, we could use pandas.

Since I don't think that pandas is a good choice for this task, I am also looking for an efficient library (if any?) to achieve this goal with proper performance

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a correct answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Comment: Implement it naively first, then start talking about relevant changes. "Millions of rows" can be done in a few seconds, which depending on your requirements, probably is fast enough for what seems like a batch task. If you want to keep only unique subject, value combinations, use a `set()` with tuples as the value in your dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward approach is to just read the file and create a dictionary of lists of `(subject, value)` tuples with `property` as the key.  If the formatting were a more standard csv format this would be easier, but it's not too hard to parse it with careful use of `split` and `join`:

```
>>> tables = {}
>>> with open("animals.txt") as f:
...     for line in f:
...         subject, prop, *v = line.strip().split(' ')
...         value = ' '.join(v[:-1])
...         tables.setdefault(prop, []).append((subject, value))
...
>>> tables
{'breed': [('dog', 'poodle'), ('dog', 'golden retriever'), ('cat', 'some breed')], 'weight': [('dog', '10'), ('cat', '15')], 'location': [('fish', 'sea'), ('cat', 'house')]}
```